# Load data when user stops swiping in fragmentviewpager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Load fragment when user stops swiping instead of previous,current,next pattern in fragmentviewpager in android? 
Load single fragment at a time in fragmentviewpager instead of multiple.

Comment: Have You tried to set small timeout before loading?

Comment: I found a work around with setUserVisibleHint() Method of Fragment.
@sandrstar Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please, add it as answer (with code) and accept, so the question will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Fragment Load FragmentViewPager sets setUserVisibleHint to true of current fragment. Through that we can put delay in loading fragment in FragmentViewPager. In Below code i have put delay of 1000 ms.

@Override
    public boolean getUserVisibleHint() {

```
    boolean isVisible = super.getUserVisibleHint();
    return isVisible;
}

public Runnable handleDelays = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
            // Application Logic    

        }
    }
};
private Handler pagerHandler;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {
            pagerHandler.removeCallbacks(handleDelays);
        } else {
            pagerHandler.removeCallbacks(handleDelays);
            pagerHandler.postDelayed(handleDelays, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        if (pagerHandler != null) {
            if (!isVisibleToUser) {
                pagerHandler.removeCallbacks(handleDelays);
            } else {
                pagerHandler.removeCallbacks(handleDelays);
                pagerHandler.postDelayed(handleDelays, 1000);
            }
        } else {
            pagerHandler = new Handler();
        }
    }
}
```